# Como trabalhar com método de busca no vueJS?

Tags: vue.js

Você percebe que a busca está funcionando perfeitamente:

https://jsfiddle.net/wladyband/8qor5c0x/

Eu queria que somente listasse os registros quando fosse digitado alguma coisa no **input search**, eu sei o que local para fazer essa alteração seria nesse trecho de código:

```
 filteredBancodedaos () {
          return this.bancodedados
          .filter((bancoDeDado)=>{
              return ( 
                bancoDeDado.name.match(this.MySearch) ||
                bancoDeDado.height.match(this.MySearch) ||
                bancoDeDado.mass.match(this.MySearch) ||
                bancoDeDado.eye_color.match(this.MySearch) ||
                bancoDeDado.gender.match(this.MySearch) ||
                bancoDeDado.hair_color.match(this.MySearch)
              )

        })
      }
    }
```

Alguém teria uma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você adicionar um `v-if` no loop para mostrar os resultados. Se sua variável `MySearch` estiver com algum valor, os resultados serão exibidos baseados na sua busca.

Veja na linha 34 do código que fiz: https://jsfiddle.net/7xz8u8tL/1/

Comment: valeu muito obrigado